# Python: start bach file and read output until specific line appear and continue

Tags: python, subprocess

So i have `batch` file that start `appium` server.

When i start execute my `batch` file i want to read the output and when the `server` running i want to continue.

I know when `appium` server running from this output:

```
Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
```

Currently this is what i have:

```
process = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\\appium.bat'])
stdout = process.communicate()[0]
print('STDOUT:{}'.format(stdout))
```

What i want is to wait up to `60` seconds or until this line appears.
In case `60` secods pass and this line (`Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723`) did not appear i want to raise `exception`.

My problem is that when my server started the process is continue to run so this never exit and continue to the next code and i cannot kill the `appium` process.

Any suggestions how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work for your case. First, it spawns a process, and wait for the timeout, while waiting, it will keep checking the output of the process. Then when the pattern is matched, it will break, or else Exception will be raised.

```
import time
import subprocess
import re


proc = subprocess.Popen(['/tmp/test.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

timeout = time.time() + 10 # adjust the timeout value here
target = ".*started on .*"

while True:
    if time.time() >= timeout:
        raise Exception("Server wasn't started")
    else:
        output = proc.stdout.readline()
        # read a line of input

        if output == '' and proc.poll() is not None:
            # process is not running anymore, 
            # proc.poll() will return None if process is still running
            raise Exception("Server process has stopped")
        else:
            line = output.decode().strip()
            if re.match(target, line):
                # if the pattern is matched, do something and break
                print("Server has started")
                break
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

This is the bash file I used to test. Save it as `/tmp/test.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "TEST"
sleep 1
echo "server has started on 0.0.0.0"
```

Comment: I try to change the target to something that will be missing and the code not raise the exception

Comment: @falukky you wish to raise exception only when the timeout occurs right? I think the `target` pattern you're using is matching. Can you tell me the `target` pattern value and the actual string you're trying to match?

Comment: @falukky you can simply try commenting out the echo statement in the `test.sh`. It will raise Exception, since the `target` pattern cannot be matched

Answer (score 1):

You can wait by using the time module

```py
import time

time.sleep(60) # wait for 60 seconds
```

Comment: But how can i exit when i got the line i want ? i cannot kill the appium process because i want to use it

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `signal.alarm`,

```
import signal
import time
import subprocess

def handler(signum, stack):
    raise Exception("It didn't happen in time...") # raise exception if it didn't come up within the time frame 

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(60)
process = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\\appium.bat'])
stdout = process.communicate()[0] # assuming this blocks
print('STDOUT:{}'.format(stdout))
signal.alarm(0) # turn of the alarm, if it came up within 60 seconds
```

if `.communicate()` is not `blocking`, then,

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen([r'C:\\appium.bat'])
stdout = process.communicate()[0] # non blocking ?
print('STDOUT:{}'.format(stdout))
time.sleep(60)
if 'Appium REST http interface listener started' not in stdout:
    raise Exception("It didn't come up in time...")
```

Comment: I am a little confused, where exactly i need to use this code and how ?

Comment: @falukky I am assuming the `.communicate()` will block until the `REST API` comes up ?

Comment: Currently my code print the process output and because the process running it never continue, and you code crash at this line:signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)

Comment: What does it say at `crash` ?

Comment: AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGALRM'

Comment: @falukky `import signal; print(signal.SIGALRM)`. It shouldn't crash :/

Comment: did `print(signal.SIGALRM)` gave you that AttributeError ?

Comment: BTW i am using python 3.x

Comment: That shouldn't matter. See `>>> import signal
>>> signal.SIGALRM` returns
`<Signals.SIGALRM: 14>`

Comment: could you just paste a screen shot for me with the content and output of `print(signal.SIGALRM)`. Because i really don't understand what is happening

Comment: Thats very strange: this still crash: signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)